# how to add two numpy.array with indices or mask

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays, like as following.

```
 a=numpy.array((1,2,3,4))
 b=numpy.array((1,2,3,4))
```

I just want to add the first two elements. How can i do it with a mask `[True, True, False, False]`, or indice `[0,1]`
After addition `b=(2, 4,3,4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply:

```
b[:2] += a[:2]
```

Or:

```
mask = numpy.array((True, True, False, False))
b[mask] += a[mask]
```